# Greedy with a trailing greedy Regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy

I am trying to get "a=.*" from the argument list in a URL (http:/a.b.com/?a=123) in Javascript.

```
/(.*[&|?])(a=.+?)(&.*)/.exec ("http:/a.b.com/?a=123&b=123")
```

gives me the expected and desired :

```
["http:/a.b.com/?a=123&b=123", "http:/a.b.com/?", "a=123", "&b=123"]
```

However, there might not be a following "&arg=val" and I need to be able to search for an optional trailing "&.*" (so adding '?' after the '&' on the third group. Hence :

```
/(.*[&|?])(a=.+?)(&?.*)/.exec ("http:/a.b.com/?a=123&b=123")
```

which gives me the unexpected :

```
["http:/a.b.com/?a=123&b=123", "http:/a.b.com/?", "a=1", "23&b=123"]
```

The second group now has only 1 character after the '=' and the remainder two '23' are part of the third group..

What I might be doing wrong ? Also any advice to do this a different/better way is also welcomed.

Thanks very much in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

- `[&?]a=(.+?)(?:&|$)`
- `[&?]a=([^&]+)`

So, either match non-greedily until you encounter a `&` or the end of the string, or match greedily all characters except `&`.

Also, I've shortened your regex and made the group only capture the value of the `a` parameter, without the `a=` part. The `.*` are not needed, your regex doesn't have to match the whole string unless it's anchored with `^` and/or `$`. And that `|` in the character class was also wrong.

Example with your test case:

```js
alert(JSON.stringify(
  /[&?]a=([^&]+)/.exec("http:/a.b.com/?a=123&b=123")
))
```

Comment: I can understand the second option and used it and worked !. I am not familiar with ?: - so just going with the second option. (thanks for pointer on ?: - will check it out). Great stuff Lucas and this was a lightening fast response !

Comment: You're welcome. FYI, `(?:...)` is equivalent to `(...)` except it doesn't capture it's value. It's only used for simple grouping.

Comment: Oh, so one could also do [&?]a=(.+?)[&|$]+    ?

Comment: No, you have to use `(&|$)` because in a character class (`[...]`), regex metacharacters lose their special meaning. So, `[&|$]` means: *one of the following characters: `&` or `|` or `$`* literally.

Comment: Used some other bits from your enhanced answer. I need to get the remainder of the URL hence the '.*'. I wrapped it with ^ and $ as per your recommendation. Alls working well. Thanks !